# I got an error when i retrieve data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am learning Mongodb from documentation and on retrieving the data I got this problem, That I could not receive the actual data. while use nodejs

***Code***

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");


const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

const client = new MongoClient(url, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});

const dbName = 'Test';
const run = async () => {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const data = db.collection('inventory').find({})
    console.log(data);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
  finally {
    await client.close();
  }
}

run().catch(console.dir);
```

**And I Got this**

```
Cursor {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: true,
  },
    ..........
}
```

I cannot figure out what is happening, why didn't I get the data

Comment: The line `const data = db.collection('inventory').find({})` should be `const data = await db.collection('inventory').find({}).toArray()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an error. You are getting a MongoDB cursor. `.find()` is async and returns a Promise of the data, not the data directly. You need to await it :

```
const data = await db.collection('inventory').find({});
```